# Programming constructs

Tags: iterator, conditional-statements

A wise man told me that to learn how a syntax works does not mean your a good programmer, but rather to grasp programming constructs like iterators and conditionals, thus, meaning you can pick up any syntax easier.
How would one go about learning these constructs??

Comment: Have a look for books on design patterns.

Comment: Well, conditionals are supported by nearly all languages but iterators only appear in the newer ones with abstract collections. For comparative syntax, you should look at http://hyperpolyglot.org/ .

Comment: The wise man said wisely. Here's an [analogy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10057916/307454) that provides perspective on constructs.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest construct you mention is a conditional.
The basic pattern of a conditional is:

```
if <some-condition> then
    <do-action>
else
    <do-other-action>
end if
```

This basic pattern is expressed in many different ways according to the language of choice, but is the basic decision-making building block of any program.

An iterator is a construct which abstracts the physical layout of a data structure, allowing you to iterate (pass through) it without worrying about where in memory each element in the data structure is.

So, for example, you can define a data structure such as any of `Array`, `Vector`, `Deque`, `Linked List`, etc.

When you go to iterate, or pass through the data structure one element at a time, the iterator presents you with an interface in which each element in the data structure follows sequentially, allowing you to loop through with a basic `for loop` structure:

```
for <element> in <data-structure>
    <do-action>
end loop
```

As for other constructs, take a look at some books on Data Structures and Algorithms (usually a 2nd-year level computer science course).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is only a technical form of expressing your solution. The way you implement and the concepts you use in your solution are the ones who makes the different between a beginner and an experienced developer. Programming languages are the means not the wits !

Comment: exactly, so, you know any good books on common constructs etc.??

Comment: thanks guys once again, big help, found some books, peace out.