# Java: why Array.length has no () but String.length() does?

Tags: java

Why when we get the length of an array don't we have to place ()
like

```
int [] ar;
System.out.println(ar.length); // no parentheses
```

but for a String it will be

```
String st;
System.out.println(st.length());
```

Comment: I don't agree that this question is the same as the earlier question, nor that the answers to that question answer this one.  The earlier question asked "How do I find the length of these different entities?" This one asks "Why do I need parentheses to get the length of a string but not the length of an array?"  I fear that the answer may be "you just do" but in any event it's not present in answers to the other question.

Comment: I also disagree. This question is about the difference between field-access and methods. If it goes into detail, its also about *why* there are different implementations inside the Java-API.

Answer (score 10):

> why Array.length has no () but String.length() does?

At the syntactic level, it really comes down to "historical reasons" and "because that's the Java (pre) 1.0 language designers decided to do it".  The only people who can truly tell you *why* are the language designers themselves.

However:

- The `length` field is special in the sense that it is actually in the array object's header, and fetching the length of an array uses a special bytecode.
- The `length` field cannot be changed by any means short of dangerous native code hacks.  It is really important that this be so, to avoid problems with heap corruption, etc.  (By contrast even a `final` field on a normal object can be modified using reflection.)

In these respects, `length` on an array is genuinely different from any other field.

---

Since the early days of (pre-)Java, the use of exposed fields in APIs has gone right out of style.

Most people would say that this is a good thing.  By exposing the length information as  `length()` and `size()` methods on strings, collections, etc, the class library design allows a Java implementor to change the representation of the respective types.  That is not possible (in Java) if fields are exposed directly.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is:

- The `length` of an array is **NOT** about the actual content - it's the dimension! An array can be of `length` 10, but only contain 2 elements.
- An Object containing elements (A String is an Object, containing multiple chars) might have a certain count of Objects inside. This count can vary, depending on whether you add or remove elements. So the `length()` method is about the actual content!

The reason is, that an array is a *language construct* - Therefore, whenever you want to know something about the array (it's length or else) You have to retrieve a *fixed* value from the JVM, rather than calling a method that evaluates *something*.

(The `Array`-Class is just a proxy for the actual *array*-construct.)

---

Technically spoken an `array` (note the small `a`) is just a memory allocation for `array.length` elements in the memory. (And that's why you can't simple resize an array, but always need to create a NEW array when changing *the dimension* - it needs to be relocated (in C that was called `realloc`) in memory, so there is enough room for `array.length * elementSize` bits.

A List on the other hand does not care about the actual position of it's element in the memory, and therefore allows dynamic resizing at any time. (So it can server a method `size()` because it has *no* dimension, and just needs to return information about it's content.)

Comment: To get your point better I looked "language contract" up and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057524/what-do-we-mean-by-language-construct but cant still make a connection. Can you add 1-2 lines about the language construct you used here

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between accessing a field (no parentheses) and calling a method (requires parentheses, even if there are no arguments to the method).

Historically, arrays *could have had* a method in addition to or instead of a field. Strings *could have had* a field in addition to a method. A field is simpler, which is probably why arrays use it, but there are at least two reasons why it's good for String to have a length method:

1. String implements the [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface, which defines a length() method, so String has to have that method. (Defining fields isn't a feature of interfaces, except for static final constants.) String could have length as a method *and* a field but that would be distracting.
2. Flexibility. String's internal implementation has changed over time: at one time it used an internal char array and separate *offset* and *length* fields which defined a region within the char array. That was done so that substrings could share the parent string's char array (with different offset and length) instead of copying the array. It was later found that that optimization was rarely beneficial, so now, String has only a char array of the correct size, and the length method reads the array's length field. String no longer has its own length field, not even a private one, but they couldn't have removed it if it were part of the class's public API, which would give less flexibility to experiment with internal implementations.

Comment: `CharSequence` was added in Java 1.4, so it is not the reason that `String` has a `length()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Array's `length` is an int field, but String (and other objects) usually use a getter method.

Do note that the difference in the two lies in the fact that a string's "length" is simply the amount of information it already stores in its internal `char` array, but an array's `length` field is just its capacity.

Comment: and that's why? Why has a object no public field, and why has array not simply a method for the length?

Comment: @dognose The length is a simple final field that can be accessed. Since array's length is immutable in the sense that you can't dynamically change the size of it, it was fine to expose that aspect of the class.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so the capacity and length are always the same.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in the eyes of reflection, not on the same level. Of course, you can't set `null` to a `char` array, but if you use something crazy like `java.misc.Unsafe`, who knows on strings, especially in reference to the length method. Array's length is not settable, even in that form.