# Does Haskell has the concept "construct" like C and ML language?

Tags: haskell, construct, referential

This wiki page: https://wiki.haskell.org/Referential_transparency talks about "C and ML are languages with constructs that are not referentially transparent." My question is, what is "Constructs"? Is it an abstract concept?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general English vocabulary.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/construct#Noun

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I'm not saying you should have *known* this was a general English vocabulary question; that's just what it turns out to be.

Comment: Oh, this appears to be a duplicate of [What does 'Language Construct' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10057524/1048572) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Construct" is being used as a general noun for things that can be constructed in those languages. You could use "thing" instead without really changing the meaning: C and ML contain things that are not referentially transparent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they refer to a *syntax* construct, not constructible things (in the OOP sense).

Comment: @Bergi syntax isn't referentially transparent or not. That's a category error. I also do not mean construction in any OOP sense.